# Find whether string is within html brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a searchresult, and I want to mark out where the string is matched.

Previously I did it with stripos and just saved the offset etc but that messed stuff up when I started to search in strings that contains html.

So, I will have a list of words that I want to mark in a text (that may contain HTML).

So, I want to find the words in the text that are not "html" syntax.
For example the string I'm looking for is 'b' then:

```
A b<abc>c
```

should be converted to

```
A <font style="color:red;">b</font><abc>c
```

and not:

```
A <font style="color:red;">b</font><a<font style="color:red;">b</font>c>c
```

The problem is I cant make that regexp. My best try is:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!<)(b)(?!>)/', '<font style="color:red;">$1</font>', 'How will this be?<abncds>Now?<br>');
```

But that doesnt catch  it only catches when the b is next to a < ofc. But adding a lazy match such as .*? doesnt work either.

Help! :)

Comment: You only want the b witch are alone ? separeted by spaces ? Or just b that are not in HTML tag ?

Comment: I always want something that is not in HTML tags, sometimes maybe its 'fo' and then i dont want it to match a part of '<font xx>xx</font>'

Comment: I think theory is that you cannot do that in general, because tags can contain scripts that can contain tags etc. - too much work for a regex. Is your HTML limited to some reasonable subset?

Comment: Yes, it's limited. It's only simple decorational tags, what is found in the http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should no the job if you're only looking within simple HTML tags:

```
preg_replace("/((^|>)[^<]+?)(your-string)/", "$1<span>$3</span>", $your_string);
```

Comment: It worked somewhat, except that:
preg_replace('/(^|>)[^<]+?(will)/', '<span>$2</span>', 'How will this be?<abncds>Now?<br>');
became:
string(42) "<span>will</span> this be?<abncds>Now?<br>"
So the first part got removed:S

Comment: Have edited since yes, it would have matched and then removed the text prior to what you wanted to get. Now capture that and add it before the span.

Comment: `preg_replace("/((?:^|>)[^<]+?)(your-string)/", "$1<span>$2</span>", $your_string);` for extra style and I'm afraid this is as good as it gets...